# OOP -- make parts aware of their whole

Tags: c++, oop

I have a singleton class called Session that looks like:

```
class Session {

    private:
      Session() throw () {};
      Session(const Session & copy) throw ();                // Not implemented.
      Session & operator= (const Session & copy) throw();    // Not implemented.

    public:
      static Session & getInstance() throw ()
      {
        static bmd2::Session instance;
        return instance;
      }
```

Session is composed of Datasets which are composed of Files (not shown in the code for simplicity).

Our usual use-case is to have an outside client, shown below, act on the Session API by calling getInstance().

```
 +--------------------------------------------+
 | Session                                    |
 |--------------------------------------------|                    +--------------------------+
 |   Session::getInstance(); <------+-----------------------------+| Client                   |
 |   instance;                      |         |                    |--------------------------|
 |                                  |         |                    |                          |
 |   +------------------------------|-------+ |                    |                          |
 |   | Dataset                      |       | |                    |                          |
 |   |------------------------------|-------| |                    |                          |
 |   |                              |       | |                    |                          |
 |   |                              |       | |                    |                          |
 |   |                              |       | |                    |                          |
 |   |                              |       | |                    |                          |
 |   |       +----------------------|-----+ | |                    +--------------------------+
 |   |       | File                 |     | | |
 |   |       |----------------------|-----| | |
 |   |       |                      |     | | |
 |   |       |                      |     | | |
 |   |       |                      |     | | |
 |   |       |                      |     | | |
 |   |       |                      +     | | |
 |   |       |                            | | |
 |   |       |                            | | |
 |   |       |                            | | |
 |   |       |                            | | |
 |   |       |                            | | |
 |   |       +----------------------------+ | |
 |   +--------------------------------------+ |
 +--------------------------------------------+
```

I recently ran into the use case where I want File and Dataset to be able to access the Session instance that they live in, also shown above.

What is the best way to make File aware of it's parent Session?  My first try was including Session.h in File.h, but it appears to have caused circular dependency problems (I got unresolved symbols all over my entire project).  I am not sure why this is so -- and if anybody could tell me based on the information provided - I'd be very thankful.  Anyway, I moved #include Session.h into File.cpp and all seemed to work.  However, I still seem fuzzy on this situation from a C++ perspective.  In Java I'd pass a reference to the whole from all the composed parts as the parts were constructed from the whole.

Comment: Add a method to _register_ `Dataset` to `Session`?

Comment: Only add to a header the #includes you absolutely need. Use forward declarations as a first choice. Anyway, trivially, just include a Session 'parent' member in each composed part. But show more c++ (and Java) code. Especially the composed parts which is the crux here. What's the use-case for the singleton?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, the parser reads class names as it parses the files.  If it sees a class name it doesn't know, it throws an error.  This means if Class A has an object of Class B referenced in it (even in a method signature), and it hasn't seen class B yet it will throw an error.  So if class A references B and class B references A, you have circular dependencies.  The solution is a forward devlaration-  you can declare a class will exist before you give the full definition.  This satisfies the parser, so long as its eventually defined.

Wiki reference on how to use them  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration